# ampps apache not starting

Tags: macos, apache, ampps

After the weekend, AMPPS Apache stopped running on Mac Mojave.

I've run the command `lsof -nP -i4TCP:80 | grep LISTEN` and received nothing back, I believe that means nothing is running on port 80.

There is nothing in the Apache error log.

I've restored Apache & PHP to default configuration through the AMPPS control panel and the issue remains.

I've reinstalled the latest version of AMPPS for Mac and the issue remains.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by installing the most recent version of AMPPS, 3.9, which is compatible with the latest version of macOS.

Answer (score 0):

apache use port 80, in my case another app used port 80 i killed it by following command:

```
kill -kill `lsof -t -i tcp:80`
```